# (ios + phone gap) - Profile final app with instruments

Tags: iphone, ios4, cordova

Is it possible to test a phonegap application for IOS with the inbuilt performance monitoring tool Instruments?

When ever i run the APP in the instruments, it says "failed to get task for pid 123".

I am using xcode 3.2.x and ios 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem because of the provisioning profile which isn't configured properly. SO to have your instruments running you need your developer and distribution profiles set in the xcode configurations properly.

Thanks